# Condition not working for me

Tags: php, mysql

I need to export CSV from MySQL Database all working fine but if have a some conditions in which second one is not working for me. it always export Absent,Holiday and sunday. but not printing `$att[$date]`  variable `$month` contain Year and month both. like - 2016-02

```
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT *, CONCAT(MIN(`IN_AM`),'  ', MAX(`OUT_PM`)) as io_time FROM bio_attandence where date(STR_TO_DATE(attandence_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) >= date('$startdate') AND date(STR_TO_DATE(attandence_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) < date('$enddATE') AND bio_id=".$row['form_no']." GROUP BY bio_id, attandence_date order by attandence_date ");
$att = array();
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) {
   $strtodate = $row1['attandence_date'];
   $dateq = str_replace('/', '-', $strtodate);
   $dateDate = date('Y-m-d', $dateq);
  $att[$dateDate] = $row1['io_time'];   
}

for($i=1; $i<32;$i++){
    $i = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $date = $month.'-'.$i;
    $val = '';
        if(strtotime($date) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))){
            $val = " ";
        }elseif(isset($att[$date])){
            $val = $att[$date];
        }elseif(isset($holidays[$date])){
            $val = $holidays[$date];
        }else{
            $val = (date('D', strtotime($date)) == 'Sun')? 'Sunday': 'Absent';
        }
    ?>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String"> <?php echo( $val ); ?></Data>
    </Cell>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_` it's deprecated and completely removed in php7. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: ok. this is my very old project. there is some update.

Comment: Please answer why my second condition not working. there is some mistake i had done.

Comment: second one. elseif(isset($att[$date])){}

Comment: what is the value for `$month` ??

Comment: the user is selecting from front end. value of month is like- 2016-11 and $i will be the date of that month.

Comment: just assign the `$att[$date]=$date;` before enter the if condition

Comment: thank you. my date format was not proper.

Comment: @Dev did you get an answer?

Comment: yes. @vasim Vanzara i found the date format error which was not currect. i change the format of the date and it works fine. and one more thing. can you please give the answer of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609441/fetch-min-in-time-and-max-out-time-from-database