# Fetch Min In Time and Max out Time From Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Table. I need to Fetch "Min In Time" and "Max Out Time" by MySQL Query. I am fetching only `IN_AM` and `OUT_PM`. How to compare `IN_AM` and `IN_PM` and comparing Two time and Fetching Min time. and Comparing Two time and fetching Max.
My Table is-

[image]

I have tried this. but not working because empty column.

```
SELECT *, 
       LEAST(IN_AM, IN_PM) AS intime,
       GREATEST(OUT_AM, OUT_PM) AS outtime
FROM 
       bio_attandence 
where 
       date(STR_TO_DATE(attandence_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) >= date('$startdate') 
AND 
       date(STR_TO_DATE(attandence_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) < date('$enddATE') 
AND 
       bio_id=".$row['form_no']." 
GROUP BY 
       bio_id, 
       attandence_date  
order by 
       attandence_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `COALESCE` as workaround for null values: `LEAST(COALESCE(IN_AM, IN_PM), COALESCE(IN_PM, IN_AM)) AS intime, GREATEST(COALESCE(OUT_AM, OUT_PM), COALESCE(OUT_PM, OUT_AM)) AS outtime` - a bit cumbersome, but should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
 Select IF(IN_AM IS NULL OR IN_PM IS NULL, COALESCE(IN_AM, IN_PM), LEAST(IN_AM,IN_PM)) AS intime,
 IF(OUT_AM IS NULL OR  OUT_AM IS NULL, COALESCE(OUT_AM,  OUT_AM), GREATEST(OUT_AM, OUT_AM)) AS outtime FROM bio_attandence where date(STR_TO_DATE(attandence_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) 
 >= date('$startdate') AND date(STR_TO_DATE(attandence_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) 
 < date('$enddATE') AND bio_id=".$row['form_no']." GROUP BY bio_id, 
 attandence_date  
 HAVING intime IS NOT NULL AND outtime IS NOT NULL
 order by attandence_date
```

Comment: thank you . when column empty it show nothing. i want opposite of that if empty column fetch other column's time.

Comment: Arrange your own way.

Comment: Tell me what are the other columns?

Comment: IF(IN_PM IS NULL OR IN_AM IS NULL, LEAST(IN_AM,IN_PM), COALESCE(IN_AM, IN_PM)) AS intime,IF(OUT_AM IS NULL OR  OUT_PM IS NULL, COALESCE(OUT_AM,  OUT_PM), GREATEST(OUT_AM, OUT_PM)) AS outtime it works fine only the second rows in intime value null.